# Using 7zip command but unable to use it with for loop

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-2.0, 7zip

I am using 7zip command to compress log files that are older than 30 days but its not working out for me. Here is the code:

```
$Pathname="G:\7za920\test"

$folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $pathname | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | Select Fullname).Fullname
#looping all folders
Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{

  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$folder" | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}

Foreach ($file in $files)
{

   ./7za.exe a -tzip archive.zip $file

}

}
```

Please help me out

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by `but its not working`? No files compressed? Wrong files compressed? Wrong archive name? Something else, what?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So, it is not compressing the files. Archive gets created, BUT inside that, its all empty :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by passing a `System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FileInfo` object to `7z.exe`. The compression program expects file name(s), not a Powershell automation object. 7Zip doesn't know what to do with the FileInfo object, so calling it will just use its `.ToString()` method that returns just the file name. This is not useful if you are in another a directory, so the command fails.

Running the compression command manually would give you a sensible error message, like so:

> PS C:> & 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' a -tzip c:\temp\archive.zip $file
>   7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
>   Scanning UpgradeLog2.htm:  WARNING: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. Creating archive c:\temp\archive.zip WARNINGS for files:
>   UpgradeLog2.htm: The system cannot find the file specified.
>   --------------- WARNING: Cannot find 1 file

The fix is easy enough, as [FileInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) contains file's full name. Use it as parameter, and 7Zip will get a full path for source.

```
./7za.exe a -tzip archive.zip $file.FullName
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that fix! I have another question. Right now the concept is all folders are getting archived into a zip file called archive.zip. What if I want each file to be zipped individually and not under a common archive. 

for example I have 3 files, a.log, b.log, c.log and now after running the script I should get a.zip, b.zip and c.zip and also the 3 log files should get deleted? What change should be made over in the script?